# Android : create realm table without primary key

Tags: android, realm

Is it possible to create a table without primary key in Realm for android

Answer (score 10):

Refer to the documentation [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#primary-keys):

> Using primary keys makes it possible to use the `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` method, which will look for an existing object with this primary key, and update it if one is found; if none is found, it will create a new object instead. When calling `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` on classes without primary keys, an exception will be thrown.

So it is possible, but you will need to use `copyToRealm()` or `insert()` methods to insert unmanaged objects, or create the managed object directly using `createObject()`.